# Function hooked to 'woocommerce_thankyou' has stopped working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

A few weeks ago, I created little hook that autocompletes orders when they consist of a particular category of product.

```
/**
 * Autocomplete orders with only an 'abo' product
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
if ( ! $order_id ) {
    return;
}

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // just in case

    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

        // check if there's an "abo" in the order, then if there's anything else.
        if ( has_term( 'abo', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
            $abo_in_order = 'true';
        }
        if ( has_term( 'goodies', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'revue', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'livre', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
            $abo_alone_in_order = 'false';
        }
        else {
            $abo_alone_in_order = 'true';
        }
    }
    // if there's an 'abo' and nothing else, change the e-mail recipient to dada@sotiaf.fr
    if ( ($abo_in_order == 'true')&&($abo_alone_in_order == 'true') ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

It used to work but hasn't for a few days, perhaps after a WooCommerce update. The whole 'has_term' part works fine as it is used in another function hooked to 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', it seems the problem comes either from the thankyou hook or from the update_status action.

Does that make sense to anyone ?

Thanks,
Joss

Edit: it appears that the code doesn't fail systematically. Some orders are still automatically marked as "complete", while others remain "pending". No difference in the contents of the orders.

Comment: Well `woocommerce_thankyou` is still there, so that should still be firing. And `$product->id` should *work* even though it has been deprecated as of WC3.0 and should be replaced with `$product->get_id()`. And [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term#Parameters) accepts an array of terms so you don't need to use the `OR` statements. None of those things should be effecting the outcome, but they'll make the code a little cleaner.

Comment: Oh thanks, Helga, it's good to know. I'm a bit weary of making changes to the code because I'm quite clumsy at it, but if I find the culprit and become a little more confident, I'll definitely do these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the culprit is your IF/ELSE condition when checking for the existence of other items in the order.

```
if ( has_term( 'goodies', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'revue', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'livre', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
     $abo_alone_in_order = 'false';
}
else {
     $abo_alone_in_order = 'true';
}
```

If the last item in the order is not in those categories, then the condition will be 'true' even if one of the previous items would have triggered it false.

Here's an example order containing 3 products

- Product 1 (abo)
- Product 2 (revue)
- Product 3 (tacos)

Product 3 would incorrectly trigger your current condition as 'true' even though the presence of Product 2 means the Product 1 abo item is not alone. So adjusting that and updating some of the rest of the code results in the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // start with assumption that there is no ABO in order
    $abo_in_order = false;

    // start with assumption that ABO is alone in order
    $abo_alone_in_order = true;


    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );


    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $item->$item->get_product();

        // check if there's an "abo" in the order, then if there's anything else.
        if ( has_term( 'abo', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $abo_in_order = true;
        }
        // if other categories exist in order abo is not alone
        if ( has_term( array( 'goodies', 'revue', 'livre' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $abo_alone_in_order = false;
        }
    }
    // if there's an 'abo' and nothing else, change order status
    if ( ( $abo_in_order && $abo_alone_in_order ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is indeed better, but as I said, the IF/ELSE part works (since there aren't any other categories) in another function that does something different under the same conditions.

Comment: Also, the code used to work, which is why I'm wondering if the hook or the update_status action no longer work the same way since the latest WooCommerce update.

Comment: `$order->update_status()` still exists. I really think your binary IF/ELSE condition was causing problems because it would return the order's status depending on the final item in the order, which may or may not always have been correct.

Comment: Alright, I've made the changes and am crossing all fingers. :-) Thank you for your time, I'll keep you posted on the results.

Comment: Hi Helga, after weeks and weeks of observing orders to try and find out why some automatically completed and others weren't, I still can't see what the reason might be. However, I've just realized that the shipping method for this special kind of order is always accurate. Could I check for the chosen shipping method, and use that instead of my "convoluted" way of checking item categories in the order?

Comment: If it is happening intermittently, it still seems like a conditional logic issue (or deeper hardware/server issue of some kind that is over my head). I did just notice a small error that I've corrected: potential undefined `$abo_in_order`, but couldn't say if that was the cause of your troubles. If the shipping method is correct, then feel free to use that for your conditional logic.

Comment: Thank you for your continued willingness to look into the matter. You wouldn't happen to know how to check the chosen shipping method? What I found dates back to before WooCommerce 3, and I'm not sure how to integrate it inside my existing code...

Comment: No. You should open a new question for that part.